# Application.DoEvents() -> Equivalent function in java?

Tags: java, swing

I know that using threads is more efficient than using c# DoEvents(), but I was still wondering whether there is an equivalent function in java. I googled for it, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: It is called event loop. This [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1996/jw-08-event.html) shows how events are handled in UI components in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Thread.yield()`, which is the java counterpart to relinquish the control of the processors voluntarily.

Comment: `Thread.yield()` would not help if the calling code is on the GUI thread, as events are dispatched on the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EventQueue.invokeLater()` to append a `Runnable` after all pending events. This have a result similar to C#'s `DoEvents()` that comes before the code you put inside the `Runnable.run()` method.

[See Java documentation for EventQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

For example, if you want to let all GUI controls to lose the focus and their lost focus events to be execute, you can use the following code:

```
@Override 
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    // Clear the focus to allow last changes to be noted. 
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearGlobalFocusOwner();
    // We want to let other events (e.g. lost focus) run before we start closing.
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // Do actual closing...
        }
    });
}
```